# Find a value within nested json dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7, nested

From the following json, in python, I'd like to extract the value "TEXT". All the keys are constant except for unknown. Unknown could be any string like "a6784t66" or "hobvp*nfe". **The value of unknown is not known**, only that it will be in that position in each json response.

```
{
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "unknown": {
        "1": "F",
        "maindata": [
          {
            "Info": "TEXT"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

one line json

```
'{"A":{"B":{"unknown":{"1":"F","maindata":[{"Info":"TEXT"}]}}}}'
```

How would you get the value of "Text"? (I know how to load the json with json.loads)..but I'm not sure how to get the value of "Text". Thanks.

(I'm not sure what the best title is.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a bit lenghty, but in that example above:

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: s = """\
   ...: {
   ...:   "A": {
   ...:     "B": {
   ...:       "unknown": {
   ...:         "1": "F",
   ...:         "maindata": [
   ...:           {
   ...:             "Info": "TEXT"
   ...:           }
   ...:         ]
   ...:       }
   ...:     }
   ...:   }
   ...: }"""

In [3]: data = json.loads(s)

In [4]: data['A']['B']['unknown']['maindata'][0]['Info']
Out[4]: u'TEXT'
```

You basically treat it as a dictionary, passing the keys to get the values of each nested dictionary. The only different part is when you hit `maindata`, where the resulting value is a list. In order to handle that, we pull the first element `[0]` and then access the `Info` key to get the value `TEXT`.

In the case of `unknown` changing, you would replace it with a variable that represents the 'known' name it will take at that point in your code:

```
my_variable = 'some_name'
data['A']['B'][my_variable]['maindata'][0]['Info']
```

And if I would have actually read your question properly the first time, if you don't know what `unknown` is at any point, you can do something like this:

```
data['A']['B'].values()[0]['maindata'][0]['Info']
```

Where `values()` is a variable containing:

```
[{u'1': u'F', u'maindata': [{u'Info': u'TEXT'}]}]
```

A single-item list that can be accessed with `[0]` and then you can proceed as above. Note that this is dependent on there only being one item present in that dictionary - you would need to adjust a bit if there were more.

Comment: I don't know what the value of unknown will be...so that won't work. Unknown could be any string.

Comment: So you just need to access whatever is at that point, regardless of the name yeah?

Comment: Yeah that's why its called unknown=P, otherwise it'd be easy to get.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a recursive function to dig through every layer and print its value with an indent

```
def recurse_keys(df, indent = '  '):
    ''' 
    import json, requests, pandas
    r = requests.post(...)  
    rj = r.json() # json decode results query
    j = json.dumps(rj, sort_keys=True,indent=2)            
    df1 = pandas.read_json(j)         
    '''
    for key in df.keys():
        print(indent+str(key))
        if isinstance(df[key], dict):
            recurse_keys(df[key], indent+'   ')
recurse_keys(df1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said that unknown was at a fixed place
You can do the following

```
import json
s=json.loads('{"A":{"B":{"unknown":{"1":"F","maindata":[{"Info":"TEXT"}]}}}}')
i=s["A"]["B"].keys()
x=i[0]   # Will store 'unknown' in x, whatever unknown is
print s['A']['B'][x]['maindata'][0]['Info']    #here x dictionary index is used after B as its value will be the value for unknown
```

This should do the job, since only the unknown key is really 'unknown'